# Identifying a Hindu Goddess

Tags: identification-request, goddess

I have been gifted a statuette by a friend of mine, but based on my limited knowledge of the Gods and Goddesses in the Hindu pantheon, and their varied iconography, I have not been able to identify the deity.

I am fairly confident that it is of Indian origin. Here are pictures of it with and without flash:

[image: God1]

---

[image: God2]

I tried a reverse image search as well, but just came up with a generic search tagged as an "antique".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deity is not a goddess. He is male.

The god in the picture is ["Ayyappa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyappan) or "Ayyappan" who is main deity of [Sabarimala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabarimala) temple, Kerala. He is son of Lord Shiva and Vishnu's incarnation Mohini. Here is an image for better comparison:

[image: Ayyappa]